# Do I have to flush a directory on Windows?

Tags: winapi, directory, filesystems, persistence, durability

On **Linux**, it's well known that after:

- creating a new file (`creat(path,..)`, `open(new_path,O_CREAT..)`), or
- deleting a file (`unlink(path)`), or
- renaming a file (`rename(src_path,dst_path)`)

One should also make sure that the changes to the directory (which in some sense is yet another file which maps human-readable names to inodes) also have been persisted to the disc in a durable way (otherwise, in case of power failure, or taking a snapshot of the volume, the directory might appear to not have the new content). In other words, these functions return before the change to the directory is made durable (which kinda makes sense, given that FS is more like DAG than a tree, so it's not even clear which directories need updating).

One can use `open(path_to_parent_dir)` to obtain a file descriptor of the directory, then `fsync(..)` it (and `close(..)` it).

On **Windows**, I see that in case of `MoveFileExA(src_path,dst_path,flags)`, I can provide the `MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH` flag, which on the one hand achieves the durability of renaming, on the other is a proof that the problem, in general, applies to Windows as well.

Thus, I wonder: what about the other operations such as:

- creating a file (`CreateFile(path,...)` with `OS_FILE_CREATE`), or
- deleting a file (`DeleteFile(path)`).

Do these functions ensure that changes to the directory containing the `path` are durable before return, or should I do call some additional, function to achieve durability?

If so, what should I do? Something like this?

```cpp
const auto dir_handle = CreateFile(path_to_parent_dir,...,FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,...);
FlushFileBuffers(dir_handle);
CloseHandle(dir_handle);
```

Comment: Typically, you do not need to flush files/directories manually. The OS caches file/directory data and will flush in the background. Certainly, sometimes flushing a file manually may be needed, but I've never heard of flushing a directory.

Comment: Sure, Remy, eventually data will reach the disc. What I want to know is what method(s) I need to call to ensure that it happens-before I get to the next line of code. Should I somehow rephrase the question to make it more explicit?

Comment: The `FlushFileBuffers()` doc says: "*If an application is performing multiple writes to disk and also needs to ensure critical data is written to persistent media, the application should use unbuffered I/O instead of frequently calling FlushFileBuffers. To open a file for unbuffered I/O, call the CreateFile function with the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH flags. This prevents the file contents from being cached and flushes the metadata to disk with each write.*" But I don't know if that applies to directories, too.

Comment: The short answer is that NTFS only guarantees that the file system will not get corrupt; file content can be lost. So the question is somewhat moot, but you don't have to flush the parent directory separately. You need to read the Windows Internals books to get the long answer.